# RecyclerView - use adapter in LinearLayouts (or use the RecyclerView with a corresponding LayoutManager)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have an `RecyclerView.Adapter` and I don't want to copy the logic to use the views in a `LinearLayout`.

So I want to know if something of the following two things is possible:

- use the `RecyclerView.Adapter` somehow in a `LinearLayout`
- create a `LayoutManager` that acts like a `LinearLayout` would do (I think this should be possible, it sounds like a good use case for that)

Is that somehow possible?

**Why?**

- display the adapter in a scrollable list (in a RecyclerView with the corresponding LayoutManager)
- display the adapter as part of list => here I need an "expanded" list which shows all items at once...

Comment: LinearLayoutManager layouts the items like a linear layout,  why you want to duplicate its code?

Comment: I wrote why... To be more precise: I use a `LinearLayout` as part of my `RecyclerView` row item and on a row click, I animate the `LinearLayout` to become visible. I now want this `LinearLayout` to be shown in some other place, but now as a normal scrollable `RecyclerView`... Therefore, it would be nice if I just write the adapter and use two different `LayoutManagers`

Comment: All you need to do is to write an Adapter that adapts your logic,  no need for layout manager

Comment: The adapter does not tell the `RecyclerView` to show all items at once... But that's what I need.

Comment: See ExpandableListConnector on how it is used in old listView to group the items, http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/widget/ExpandableListConnector.java#ExpandableListConnector

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible (or if it is, that it's recommended) to have an expanded RecyclerView.

If you do want to add all the items from your adapter in a linearlayout, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
   LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    for(int position=0; position<mAdapter.getItemCount(); position++){
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ll, mAdapter.getItemViewType(position));
        mAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);

        ll.addView(holder.itemView);
    }
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it be recommended? Of course, it can't use view recycling, but it's only a way of displaying the data and that is by design not the function of a `RecyclerView` but of the `LayoutManager`... Your solution would be a workaround I was aware of as I already did this with a `ListAdapter`... I still would prefer a `LayoutManager` as it seems to be designed for exactly that... Thanks though

Comment: Your answer is useful though... But you loose the adapter functions like notifying and so... Still, for displaying it's useful

Answer (score 1):

We solve this by creating a different controller, which binds only one single view.

The controller:

```
ViewItemController
   static class ItemViewHolder {
        View txtTitle;
   }

   private ItemViewHolder holder;

   public void bindView(Object dataModel) {
       holder.txtTitle.setText(dataModel.toString());
   }

   public void createViewHolder(View root) {
        holder = new ItemViewHolder;
        // Populate holder with Butterknife/findViewById
   }
}
```

Usage in RecyclerAdapter:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewItemController itemController;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemController = new ViewItemController();
        itemController.createViewHolder(itemView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemController.bindView(model.get(position));
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View itemView = inflateLayout...
     return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Usage in a detailview:

```
private void bindDetailView(View itemView, Object dataModel) {
    ViewItemController itemController = new ViewItemController();
    itemController.createViewHolder(itemView);
    itemController.bindView(dataModel);
}
```